# How can I convert data contained if yes do somethings or no don't do anything to table in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I have data I want to looking to design table as in the picture

Comment: Are you looking for the Table design for this ?

Comment: yes  Jayasurya Satheesh

Answer (score 0):

Create a table with the following design

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.MyData
(
    SeqNo INT IDENTITY(1,1) CONSTRAINT Pk_MyDate_SeqNo PRIMARY KEY,
    Diseases VARCHAR(255),
    YesNo BIT CONSTRAINT Df_MyData_YesNo DEFAULT(0),
    Duration INT,
    Treatement VARCHAR(255)
)
```

Insert the value 1 To the Column YesNo for value Yes for No insert Value 0